# Convert Polygon to SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

I have a dictionary

```
"polygon": [[168.4456025, 54.51134820], [168.4458053, 54.50852270], [168.445539, 54.48874220], [168.4419135, 54.4690740], [168.4254386, 54.57088510], [168.4356331, 54.55147240], [168.4423761, 54.5315580], [168.4456025, 54.5113482]]
```

How to convert it to polygon for sql?

As a result, I should receive a similar request

```
INSERT INTO public.locations (id, title, polygon) VALUES (
    '7', 'Test',
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(
(168.4456025 54.51134820, 168.4458053 54.50852270, 168.445539 54.48874220, 168.4419135 54.4690740, 168.4254386 54.57088510, 168.4356331 54.55147240, 168.4423761 54.5315580, 168.4456025 54.5113482)
)')
);
```

Those. I need to somehow bring my dictionary in python with coordinates to this

```
(168.4456025 54.51134820, 168.4458053 54.50852270, 168.445539 54.48874220, 168.4419135 54.4690740, 168.4254386 54.57088510, 168.4356331 54.55147240, 168.4423761 54.5315580, 168.4456025 54.5113482)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to convert the dictionary (`dict`) to the string passed into the insert statement:

```py
'POLYGON((' + ', '.join(list(map(lambda x: ' '.join(str(n) for n in x), dict['polygon']))) + '))'
```

You can update the prepended/appended strings as necessary.

I am not too familiar with python coding standards, so this might be a bit unorthodox, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html), it will perform common transformations for you.

Postgis takes Polygons defined as Well-Known-Text (wkt).

In `shapely` the `.wkt` attribute is available to you:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

shape = {
"polygon": [[168.4456025, 54.51134820], [168.4458053, 54.50852270], [168.445539, 54.48874220], [168.4419135, 54.4690740], [168.4254386, 54.57088510], [168.4356331, 54.55147240], [168.4423761, 54.5315580], [168.4456025, 54.5113482]]
}
poly = Polygon(shape["polygon"])
poly.wkt
```

> 'POLYGON ((168.4456025 54.5113482, 168.4458053 54.5085227, 168.445539 54.4887422, 168.4419135 54.469074, 168.4254386 54.5708851, 168.4356331 54.5514724, 168.4423761 54.531558, 168.4456025 54.5113482))'